# Mesh-R-CNN Data with Colab and Pytorch3D

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory, pytorch3d

While using the Mesh-R-CNN demo on Google Colab:
https://github.com/facebookresearch/meshrcnn

on the **demo.py** file I get this message

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-202aa0a6d1de> in <module>()
     17 
     18 # required so that .register() calls are executed in module scope
---> 19 import meshrcnn.data  # noqa
     20 import meshrcnn.modeling  # noqa
     21 import meshrcnn.utils  # noqa

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meshrcnn.data'
```

what should I do to import successfully Meshrcnn.data?!

I also don't know how to work with the config setting present in the repo. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since it was colab it was missing the "! cd" on the previous import of MeshRCNN